# payu user defined fields max length

Tags: payu, payumoney

I am currently working on payu integration to my website, Here I need to send 256 characters (alphanumeric) in `udf1`, Is this possible ? what is the max length of these `user defined fields`? where can I get the proper demo and documentation for payu, Currently I am referring [this](https://developer.payubiz.in/documentation/Response-parameters/25).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

250 is the max length for payu `user defined fields`